# Div 2 Column Set up using images and block-links inline-block not working - Shopify/liquid

Tags: html, css, liquid

Thanks for your patience with me hopefully someone can help me get this thing sorted. The OLD JSFiddle has been manipulated so many times I've just left off where I was last. I've started a new one hopefully in a cleaner, better direction. I'm no professional so again I don't know every rule, especially CSS. Thanks.

Important stuff:

OLD JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/Craftworksatb/qot0aj9h/18/

NEW JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/Craftworksatb/h4L3dyLw/

I'm working with Shopify's Liquid trying to fix up the index page so that it doesn't look like a mess of product collections flying all over the page. So here's where I decided to come up with a whole new mess:

Basically all I want to do (after hours and hours of toying and fiddling and positioning, displaying, google searching.. etc etc. again, not a pro) All I want to do is have two columns which are set up with 2 different sized images, one of those images (Furniture Gallery) has links associated with it as you'll see in the OLD JSFiddle. The second Column has 3 different sized images in the second column, those are basic links. You'll see this sort of layout in the OLD Jsfiddle. I keep thinking I'm getting somewhere, but.. as you can see I'm a bit stuck. I started the newest JSfiddle to kind of narrow down what I was doing wrong..

Newest code below:

HTML:

```
    <div id="mid-page" class="container padded-row">
  <div id="furni-card" class="mcard">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0805/3379/files/Furni-clickd.jpg?12824279880080276008" class="furniture-gall-card container" alt="">
    <a href="https://www.peterboroughcraftworks.ca/collections/Furniture-Gallery" class="fg-link"> </a>
    <a href="https://www.peterboroughcraftworks.ca/collections/dining-furniture" class="df-link"> </a>
    <a href="https://www.peterboroughcraftworks.ca/collections/coffee-and-end-tables" class="cef-link"> </a>
    <a href="https://www.peterboroughcraftworks.ca/collections/office-furniture" class="offi-link"> </a>
    <a href="https://www.peterboroughcraftworks.ca/collections/bedroom" class="bed-link"> </a>
    <a href="https://www.peterboroughcraftworks.ca/collections/living-and-entertainment" class="lae-link"> </a>
    <a href="https://www.peterboroughcraftworks.ca/collections/bars-islands" class="bii-link"> </a>

    <div id="cusm">
      <a href="https://www.peterboroughcraftworks.ca/pages/furniture-options">
        <img border="0" alt="Hooks & Knobs" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0805/3379/files/cusm.jpg?12667808716500648615" height="223" width="312">
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>



  <div id="produside" class="mcard">
    <div id="shop-new">
      <a href="https://www.peterboroughcraftworks.ca/collections/craftworks-store">
        <img border="0" alt="Shop Online Now!" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0805/3379/files/welcome-spring.jpg?16540889492977978359" width="640" height="435">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div id="hooksk">
      <a href="https://www.peterboroughcraftworks.ca/collections/hooks-knobs">
        <img border="0" alt="Hooks & Knobs" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0805/3379/files/Hooksknobs.jpg?9884174894376543046" width="640" height="217">
      </a>
    </div>


    <div id="spabeaut">
      <a href="https://www.peterboroughcraftworks.ca/collections/spa-beauty">
        <img border="0" alt="Spa & Beauty" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0805/3379/files/beautyspa.jpg?9884174894376543046">
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

*note the classes of padded row and container are already defined in the complete styles sheet the part below is just a snippet. Maybe the other CSS is overriding my new CSS?

CSS:

```
     #midpage .container .padded-row {
max-width: 900px;
margin: auto;
position: relative;
  }


#furnicard .mcardl {
display: inline;
vertical-align: top;
max-width: 100px;

}

#produside .mcardr {
vertical-align: top;
width: auto;
}


  .mcardl {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;  
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
}
.mcardr {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 900px) {

  .mcardl {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
  }
  .mcardr {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #furnicard .mcardl {
   display: inline;
vertical-align: top;
max-width: 100px;


}

#produside .mcardr {
    vertical-align: top;
width: auto;

}
  }
```

I some how need to incorporate this css back in there.. Should I have had one class of link and then just did the inline styling for it in the HTML?

```
a.fg-link {
  display: inline;
  height: 640px;
  width: 312px;
  z-index: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  margin: 0;
}

a.df-link {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 60px;
  margin: 0;
}

a.cef-link {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 160px;
  margin: 0;
  top: 60px;
}

a.offi-link {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  top: 210px;
}

a.bed-link {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 160px;
  margin: 0;
  top: 210px;
}

a.lae-link {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  height: 160px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 380px;
}

a.bii-link {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  height: 160px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 160px;
  top: 380px;
}
```

To Review:

Looking to get the layout down with 2 columns, first column featuring the 2 images, and second column featuring the three images. Also need to have those corresponding links positioned on top of the Furniture Gallery image (you'll see that in the OLD JSfiddle). This also needs to be responsive to cellphones/ipads/tablets, I don't care if it pushes them back to vertical stacking as long as they fill the media screen (thus the media query)...

So what do you guys think? I know it's a bit of a mess and I've got lots of questions, but I'd prefer just to get the positioning on my page down and I can somehow figure out the rest! I appreciate any slight help or tips/tricks to fix this!

Answer (score 1):

I have to say you were right it was a mess but I think I've accomplished what you are trying to do.

A couple of tips for learning:

It helps as a matter of structure to come up with a system. There is no need to define a left and right column `.mcardl` or `.mcardr` if you define the class in the first place. I just called it `mcard`

You must double check that your classes in the html match what you've declared in the css. You had some missing dashes in the css. If you leave those out your styles will not impact the html.

You do not need to define the same properties in every class in every breakpoint, you has `vertical-align: top;` properties and `display-inline` on almost every class and id.

Lastly for your container which was a main issue, if you define the columns there is no need to have `max-width: 1000px;` AND to define `width: 900px;`

I've cleaned it up. Let me know if you have more questions and see the below fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/gward90/h4L3dyLw/13/

Comment: Definitely went over kill with a bunch of things, but it was getting copied and pasted from various copies (after a few months of researching this stuff builds up!) It totally became a mess, thank you for clarifying these things for me! Seriously helped, you rock! 

I did have the singular mcard in one of the copies, thats lost in the oblivion now. 

Thanks again for the tips and the learning. I'll get there!

Comment: And as you can see works fine in JSFiddle, but no good on the website, which has lead me to believe some previous styling is forcing it to stack vertically and ignore all my other styles: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0805/3379/files/error_stuff.png?5540692981268677534 Onward-ho I guess at finding out what exactly might be causing this.

Comment: @ARobit can you provide a URL to your site ?

Comment: Yup. I don't have this code in place at the moment, don't know if that matters. Here: http://www.peterboroughcraftworks.ca

Comment: @ARobit let me know when you add it to the site or on a development server. I'll be glad to help further.

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a try...and this should get you at least a step in the right direction. A couple of notes:

- I'm using Flexbox for the layout to fill the space horizontally
- You should use an image map to have separate links for the image areas, I have already implemented one for you, but the rest would follow suit.

**HTML**

```
<div id="mid-page" class="container padded-row">
  <div id="furni-card" class="mcardr">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0805/3379/files/Furni-clickd.jpg?12824279880080276008" class="furniture-gall-card container" alt="" usemap="#mymap">

    <map name="mymap">
      <area alt="" title="" href="https://www.peterboroughcraftworks.ca/collections/dining-furniture" shape="rect" coords="0,60,150,220" style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
    </map>

    <div id="cusm">
      <a href="https://www.peterboroughcraftworks.ca/pages/furniture-options">
        <img border="0" alt="Hooks & Knobs" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0805/3379/files/cusm.jpg?12667808716500648615" height="223" width="312">
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>



  <div id="produside" class="mcardl">
    <div id="shop-new">
      <a href="https://www.peterboroughcraftworks.ca/collections/craftworks-store">
        <img border="0" alt="Shop Online Now!" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0805/3379/files/welcome-spring.jpg?16540889492977978359" width="640" height="435">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div id="hooksk">
      <a href="https://www.peterboroughcraftworks.ca/collections/hooks-knobs">
        <img border="0" alt="Hooks & Knobs" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0805/3379/files/Hooksknobs.jpg?9884174894376543046" width="640" height="217">
      </a>
    </div>


    <div id="spabeaut">
      <a href="https://www.peterboroughcraftworks.ca/collections/spa-beauty">
        <img border="0" alt="Spa & Beauty" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0805/3379/files/beautyspa.jpg?9884174894376543046">
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#mid-page {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Is this close to what you're looking for?

Comment: Aha! This is very close, thank you for introducing the idea of image maps. I hadn't heard of that, time to do more research! I've applied this to the website, but it's still defaulting everything back to vertical stacking. It's gotta be something that's been predetermined by previous CSS styles.. Hmm. I'll just have to keep hunting, but thank you loads your input and the idea of mapping sounds like it'll be super useful in this instance.